# different navigation in localhost vs. iis (without/within the appname)

Tags: asp.net, iis, navigation, localhost

I have a web application, that developed in the Asp.net environment (version: 2022, languages: c #, javaScript).

When I run it locally (with localhost) the url is without the app name.
But when I upload it to IIS, the url includes the app name.

This affects my routing within the application (in html, js, razor).

Do I have a way to solve this problem at the app level?

Thanks

Comment: Then show us your IIS Express (localhost) and full IIS (upload target) configuration for both cases, or troubleshooting cannot get started.

Comment: Have you tried removing the application name using URL rewrite rules in IIS? By the way, are you running the MVC application on IIS?

Comment: @LexLi Where are these configurations located? I would appreciate it if you could explain

Comment: @JennyDai your solution it's just for display. itsn't it? It will not help me in the internal mappings.

Comment: You should learn from a search engine, as tons of materials cover those for decades. I wrote two, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/iis.html#local-iis-server and https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file